# Need VB code to paste data retrived during runtime in QTP script in a column of an Excel sheet.

Tags: vba, excel, qtp

I am running a QTP script where a data is produced dynamically. I am retrieving the data during runtime and then I need to paste that data in an Excel sheet (in a column). Please suggest how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim excls
set excls=Createobject("Excel.Application")
set Book=excls.workbooks.add
set sheet1=Book.activesheet
sheet1.cells(1,1)="******** ********"
sheet1.saveas "Path of file"
excls.quit
```

---

Second model

```
Datatable.addsheet "Sheet name"
datatable.importsheet"File name,source sheer","destination sheet"
'now all the data are stored in sheet name at run time
'any query pls mail to me : vasuth2008@gmail.com
```